# Data not binding to ngModel what should i do

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs

when i want to update form all data save but  date not save in database what should i do

here is code

$scope.OnEditMode = function (obj) {
$scope.selectedObject = obj;

```
        $scope.selectedObject.Date = formatDateObject($filter, dateParser($scope.selectedObject.Date));
        $scope.selectedObject.Deadline = formatDeadlineObject($filter, dateParser($scope.selectedObject.Deadline));

        $scope.dateParse = function (obj) {
            return dateParser(obj);
        }

    }

    var formatDateObject = function ($filter, date) {
        return $filter('date')(date, "dd/MM/yyyy");

    }
    var formatDeadlineObject = function ($filter, date) {
        return $filter('date')(date, "dd/MM/yyyy");

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Are you currently receiving the date value in your backend? If the date format is incorrect, it may not be able to be stored in the database. To help us better understand your issue, could you please share the data type of the date column in your database table? Thank you!